# Database entities (models) required for Cosmos database

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api, azure-cosmosdb, azure-cosmosdb-sqlapi

**Question1:**
Earlier, we are using WebApi+SqlServer and now we want to migrate to WebApi+Cosmos DB.

**Earlier Implementation(WebApi+SqlServer):**
1. We have created one Employee model which will be a map to an object that comes from UI(postman here)
2. Later we will perform validations on that model in WebApi.
3. Next, that model will be map to DatabaseEmployee(SQL server) entity and insert into the SQL server.

**New Implementation(WebApi+CosmosDB -SQL API+DocumentDB):**
1. Step1 and Step2 of above will be done here as well
2. Do we need to create a DatabaseEmployee entity here as well or else we can directly insert data into CosmosDB without mapping the Employee model to DatabaseEmployee model?

**Note:**
I think:
a) One-One mapping: no need to create a CosmosDB entity(DatabaseEmployee).
b) One-Many mapping: we should create a CosmosDB entity(DatabaseEmployee).
c) Many-Many mapping: we should create a CosmosDB entity(DatabaseEmployee).

**Question2:**
For One-Many mapping consider the following example 2 tables Employee and Department:
Employee:   EmpID, Name, Address
Department: DeptID, DeptName,EmpId
In SQL Server we have foreign key constraints so we can maintain 2 tables.
In Cosmos DB, do we need to create 2 different containers or else 1 container is sufficient as below?

```
{
DeptId:101,
DeptName: "XXX",
EmpData:
  {
     EmpId: 101,
     Empname:"AAA"
  },
 {
     EmpId: 102,
     Empname:"BBB"
 }
}
```

If one container is sufficient then my UI model must be as below:

```
Public class Department
{
  public int DeptId {get;set;}
  public string Deptname {get;set;}
  public List<Employee> EmpData {get;set;}
}
```

But we have models like :

```
public class Employee
{
 public int EmpId {get;set;}
 public string EmpName {get;set;}
}

public class Department
{ 
 public int DeptId {get;set;}
 public string DeptName {get;set;}
 public int EMpId {get;set;}  ** ForeignKey constraint as per SQL server **
}
```

**Note:**
How to maintain the model in WebApi and how to create database entities that resemble CosmosDB container?

Comment: Why do you want to move to CosmosDB? CosmosDB uses a different database paradigm compared to a traditional Relational DB like SQL Server and it may not be appropriate to use Cosmos for OLAP workloads, for example.

Answer (score 0):

For many-to-many relationships we recommend to use two containers and use Change Feed to keep the data in sync between them. However you would only do this if you do high volumes of reads and writes for both departments and employees. It appears here that department entity is nearly static and employees change frequently. So this all depends on how you access data and you should experiment to see which is the most efficient model and partition key strategy.

The department container would have departmentId as it's partition key with a new document for each employee. I would not embed employees inside a department document as it could hit the max doc size of 2MB. Also if you frequently update department with small changes to employees this would be expensive.

I would model data in department container like this.

```
{
    deptId:101,
    deptName: "XXX",
    type: "department"
}

{
     empId: 101,
     empName:"AAA",
     deptId: 101,
     type: "employee"
 }
```

To get all employees for a department you would write a query like this.

```
Select * FROM c WHERE c.deptId = 101
```

This would return both the department record and all its employees. As read through the result set in your code you check the "type" property and de-serialize into the correct class type.

On the Employee side you do the opposite. Your partition key would be employeeId and would   have a model like this.

```
{
     empId: 101,
     empName:"AAA",
     deptId: 101
}
```

Updates to the department Id would be done on the employees container only. Using Change Feed you'd listen to the changes and then do an upsert on the departments container to keep them in sync (this is how you do referential integrity in a NoSQL database).

There is a lot of great docs on how model and partition your data in Cosmos DB. I would definitely read these to understand how to best design for Cosmos.

[Model data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/modeling-data)

[Partition data](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/partitioning-overview)

[Real world example](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cosmos-db/how-to-model-partition-example)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Is there any chance the Change Feed listeners may miss a message or otherwise fail? Are there any guarantees about database state when using Change Feed listeners to implement referential integrity?

Comment: Yes, you should implement a dead-letter queue in your exception handlers then handle via another process to retry processing. If you are actively listening and processing from change feed you will not miss changes however, if your interval is exceptionally long you will only see the latest update on an item. Change Feed is not a true oplog, it only stores the most recent version on an item. Generally for most scenarios this is fine as the purpose is to keep the two containers in sync.